# Handle back button with react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

If a user navigates to **www.example.com/one** and clicks the back button, I want to redirect them to **www.example.com**.

I think it's a common problem, but I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: I don't think that's how the back button us supposed to work... The user should go to www.example.com first, then navigate to www.example.com/one and when it presses the BACK button, go back to www.example.com

Comment: *Not using browser back button* But imagine this scenario, where you order an item in amazon and order details comes to you email, as soon as you click on view order details it takes to to amazon.com/order/:orderID then if he clicks back he should be navigated to amazon.com not back to email. how to do it?

Answer (score 34):

**Hooks version (React 16.8+):**

Minimal version.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export const Item = () => {
    let history = useHistory();
    return (
        <>
          <button onClick={() => history.goBack()}>Back</button>
        </>
    );
};
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question refers to the browser's back button. Why on earth would developers build their own Back button into an app when the browser already has one is beyond me.

Comment: Yes, it works exactly the same as the browser's back button. However, what if the browser doesn't have a Back button? The perfect example would be in Progressive Web App. (Not a browser but)

Comment: Not using browser back button But imagine this scenario, where you order an item in amazon and order details comes to you email, as soon as you click on view order details it takes to to amazon.com/order/:orderID then if he clicks back he should be navigated to amazon.com not back to email. how to do it?

Comment: @HOLLAMUKUNDA in this case you could simply put a link to amazon.com.

Comment: This won't work with the browser's back button. I added a solution for that in https://stackoverflow.com/a/66046495/1724285

Comment: @AndroidDev I know this is an old comment but to answer your question, I use react for Desktop and Mobile apps.

Answer (score 31):

In **react-router-dom v6** `useHistory()` is replaced by `useNavigate()`. so use `useNavigate()` inplace of `useHistory()` this way.

```
import { useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";

export const Item = () => {
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    return (
        <>
          <button onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>Back</button> 
        </>
    );
};
```

for more on **useNavigate** visit this: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigate

Answer (score 6):

You can try with two options, either you can use `push` method or `goBack` method from history of the router. Normally history props will available if you directly route the component via `Route` method or pass the history props to child component and use it.

Sample Code given below

```
this.props.history.push('/') //this will go to home page

or

this.props.history.goBack() //this will go to previous page
```

For your problem you try with `push` method and give the exact url you to move on.

For more reference visit https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history

Answer (score 3):

What you want is this:

Let's say a person goes to a single page in your website such as: www.yoursite.com/category/books/romeo-and-juliet

In this page, you want to show a "Back" button that links you to one upper directory which is: www.yoursite.com/category/books/

This is breadcrumb system that we famously had in vBulletin forums and such.

Here is a basic solution to this:

```
let url = window.location.href;
let backButtonUrl = "";
if (url.charAt(url.length - 1) === "/") {
  backButtonUrl = url.slice(0, url.lastIndexOf("/"));
  backButtonUrl = backButtonUrl.slice(0, backButtonUrl.lastIndexOf("/"));
} else {
  backButtonUrl = url.slice(0, url.lastIndexOf("/"));
}
```

What it basically does is: 
1. Get the current URL from browser
2. Check if there is a "/" (slash) at the end of the link.
  a. If there is: remove the slash, and remove everything the last slash
  b. If there is not: remove everything last slash.

You can use `{backButtonUrl}` as your Go Back button link.

Note: it does not have anything to do with React Router, history, etc.
Note 2: Assuming you are using a link architecture that goes like www.site.com/word/letter/character

If you want to use it with `react-router-dom` library, then you need to set your url variable like this:

`let url = this.props.match.url;`

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem today. I have the following flow in one of the applications I'm working on:

1. User fills out a registration form
2. User enters credit card "payment page"
3. When payment is successful, the user sees a "payment confirmation" page.

I want to prevent the users from navigating from the "payment confirmation" (3) page back to any previous steps in the payment flow (1 and 2).

The best thing to do would be not to use routes to control which content is displayed, and use state instead. If you cannot afford to do that,
I found two practical ways to solve the problem:

1. Using React-Router:

- When you hit the back button, React Router's history object will look like this:

[image]

- When you go to any page using `history.push` record the page you are visiting in the state
- Create a decorator, HOC, or whatever type of wrapper you prefer around the React-Router's `Route` component. In this component: If `history.action === "POP"` and `"history.state.lastVisited === <some page with back navigation disabled>"`, then you should redirect your user to the /home page using `history.replace`

2. Another way to do is is by going to the /home page directly:
   Use history.action to detect the back button was used, then:

- Change location.href to equal the page you want to visit
- Call `location.reload()`. This will reload the application, and the history will be reset

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. It's not beautiful but it works.

```
class Restaurant extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.props.history.push('/');
        this.props.history.push(this.props.match.url);
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

i'am search for many time ! you can use state option from navigation method :

`navigation(route, {state: {canBack: true}})`

and in your back button

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
const location = useLocation();
    
const goBack = () => {
  navigate(-"1);
}

location.state?.canBack // check if user can back
```

Answer (score 0):

Browser back button works on your routes history. It will not invoke your programmatically handled routing. That's the point where we should keep maintain history stack with react router. If you are at route `'/'` and push `'/home'`. On browser back button it will pop `'/home` and will go back to `'/'`.

Even If you implement`Button` component for go back functionality and use react router `history props`. Believe me you have to carefully manage your navigation to maintain browser history stack appropriately. So it behaves same like whether you press browser back button or your app `Button` to go back or go forward. 
I hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

We wanted something similar for our React app and unfortunately this was the best solution we came up with. This is particularly helpful when our users are on mobile devices and they land on a specific page on our site from an ad or a `referrer`.

This is in our main `routes.tsx` file.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    // The path that the user is supposed to go to
    const destinationPath = location.pathname;

    // If our site was opened in a new window or tab and accessed directly
    // OR the page before this one was NOT a page on our site, then...
    if (
      document.referrer === window.location.href ||
      document.referrer.indexOf(window.location.host) === -1
    ) {
      // Replaces the current pathname with the homepage
      history.replace("/");

      // Then pushes to the path the user was supposed to go to
      history.push(destinationPath);
    }
  }, []);
```

Now when a user presses the back button, it takes the user to our homepage instead of being stuck within the "nested" route they were in.

**NOTE:** There are some small quirks with this implementation. Our app is also a [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) app so we NEED to have our own back button. This implementation works well with our own back button but does not seem to work with the native browser's back button; hence, it worked well for our needs.

Comment: Adding a note for others. history.listen and setState work well together (even under v6, but you need to use the history package instead)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using  `../` or `useNavigate`

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
.
.
.
<Link to="../" relative="path"> Back </Link>
```

**Or** (recommended)

```
import { useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
.
.
.
const navigate = useNavigate();
.
.
.
<button onClick={() => navigate(-1)}> Back </button>
```

**Source**: [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate) v6.11.1